# Replace every second comma with space using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am looking to replace every second comma on every line of a text file with a space using sed or awk in the Linux terminal. The file looks like:

```
1,2,5,32,67,28,40,30...
2,4,90,18,22,40,20,15....
```

and I want a specific software input file format:

```
1,2 5,32 67,28 40,30
2,4 90,18 22,40 20,15...
```

I tried

```
sed -r 's/([^,]+ +[^,]) +/\1\s/g' Test.txt > Test2.txt
```

but this did not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(.\{3\}\),/\1 /g' input_file
1,2 5,32 67,28 40,30...
2,4 90,18 22,40 20,15....
```

Comment: very clever and elegant answer. please explain.

Comment: @DudiBoy It is actually quite fragile. It will match any 3 characters, then break on a comma at second occurance. As it is wrapped to exclude a comma on every fourth occurrance, the first set of integers matched before the first comma must not exceed 2 characters, so 100+ will break it, however, the amount of integers before the second comma can be any amount. In regards to the sample provided, it will work but has limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/(,[^,]*),/\1 /g' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `(,[^,]*),` matches and captures into Group 1 a comma and then any zero or more chars other than a comma, and then matches a comma
- `\1`  replaces the match with Group 1 value and adds a space right after.

The `-E` option enables POSIX ERE regex syntax.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Iszohp):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='1,2,5,32,67,28,40,30...
2,4,90,18,22,40,20,15....'
sed -E 's/(,[^,]*),/\1 /g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
1,2 5,32 67,28 40,30...
2,4 90,18 22,40 20,15....
```

Comment: thank you so much! that worked perfectly and I appreciate the details in your reply.

Answer (score 0):

slighly verbose awk-based solution that's confirmed working on gawk, mawk-1, mawk-1.996, and nawk :

```
[g/m/n]awk 'sub("^"(_="[^,]+,")_,"&"(_="\3\21"))sub(","_," ")_'
```

I picked `\032\021` as a safer choice than merely going with subsep, since the chance of this combo appearing is rather low. A more concise solution would be like

```
 mawk 'sub("^"(_="[^,]+,")_,"&\5")sub(",\5"," ")_'
```